# What happens when a symmetry element is added or removed from a point group?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

What new point group is formed if symmetry element *i* is added to *C3* point group?

Comment: Then it's not a group.

Comment: @Zhe the book answer says that S6 point group is formed

Comment: A group plus one extra element is usually not a group at all. A group plus one extra element _and the elements produced by it_ is usually another, bigger group (in this case $S_6$).

Comment: The set is not closed under composition, so it's not a group. If you take the closure with $i$, then yes, it's $S_{6}$. The easiest way to see is to write out the elements of the group.

Comment: @IvanNeretin how do we know what bigger group is formed let's say if we add $i$ to $C_{3v}$

Comment: If it isn't obvious right away, we may have to write down all elements of the new group, one by one.

Comment: @IvanNeretin the element added will combine with all the existing elements to generate new elements, how do we find what new elements are created in non trivial cases?

Comment: Like you said: we combine the new element with all the existing elements, thus getting some new elements, then we _do the same with them_ and so on, until we stop getting any new elements.

Comment: I combine $C_{3}$ and $i$ by applying operations on point (x,y,z) and get a new point, how would I know to which symmetry element the new point corresponds?

Comment: Forget the points, work with matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Inversion $i$ is equivalent to a two-fold improper rotation $S_2$. Introducing a $2n$-fold improper rotation axis to the existing $C_n$ point group will result in a new $S_{2n}$ point group, e.g. in your case $C_3 ⊗ i = S_6$.

Comment: Is there a way to solve for the new group

Comment: Can it be solved using a character table?

Comment: @rishabhx64 Yes, but that would be an overkill for this case.

Comment: I'd say character tables are not for this purpose at all.

Comment: @andselisk take this case add $i$ to $C_{3v}$

Comment: @IvanNeretin how do we solve such questions then? The thing is that the chapter in which this question is given in my textbook, has not introduced character tables, and I can't find a way to solve such questions